# MYSQL substring of varying length after x but before y

Tags: mysql, url, substring

I'm a newbie to MYSQL and using PhpMyAdmin to work on my database.

The problem is I have an URL mixed in with regular old text that I'm trying to extract to use somewhere else.  It is not always the same length.

```
SELECT
 SUBSTRING(description, LOCATE('X', description)+6)
FROM table WHERE id=56;
```

So this gives me everything that comes after "X".

I need something that can pull out everything in between 2 known identifiers.
Possible?

Comment: What you need exactly ? If the description is "jjksdj'dfld'dfdf'" ,what should be your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(description, LOCATE('X', description)+6), Y, 1)
FROM table
WHERE id=56;
```

Per the MySQL manual:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count) Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for delim.
```

Comment: Wow!  That's brilliant!  Thank you!  What does the number 1 after the Y, signify?  Can it be any positive number?

Comment: Glad I could help. I added an explanation of the SUBSTRING_INDEX function to my answer.